# Calculating correlation between two different gene set of different size using R

Tags: r, matrix, correlation

From my [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30010410/filtering-correlation-data-from-psyche-package-in-r), I got the idea of generating correlation matrix and subsequent filtering the values for an input matrix.

A problem arise is :I have a list of 8000 genes and would like to compare its correlation with only 200 other genes. If I include those 200 genes with 8000 and run the following code, an 8200*8200 correlation matrix will be generated and very difficult to extract my choice of pairs.

```
library(psych)
myData <- read.clipboard.tab(header = TRUE)
myData1 <- myData[-1]
rownames(myData1) <- myData[,1]
Corrt <- corr.test(t(myData1))
```

According to the help files, user can input 2 matrix, but **should be having same no of rows**. So it is impossible in my case.

So my doubt is, what method should I follow (or any other packages in R)if I need to calculate correlation values between 2 different  gene set of different size?

edit:

File 1

```
genes     exp1   exp2   exp3 ...   exp 400

gene1     val1   val2   val3 ...   val 400
.
.
gene 8000 val1   val2   val3 ......val 400
```

File 2

```
genes     exp1   exp2   exp3 ...   exp 400

gene1     val1   val2   val3 ...   val 400
.
.
gene 200  val1   val2   val3 ......val 400
```

Comment: I'm guessing (but I don't know this package) that the genes are supposed to be the columns and so are supposed to be measured on the same population, hence the same number of rows?

Comment: (`cor` function of `base R`also permits to compute only the correlation coefficients you want)

Comment: In my case, there is microarray values for 8000 genes in one file and 200 genes in another file. I want to check the correlation of each of 8000 genes to all 200 genes. @CathG

Comment: Are the 8200 genes measured on the same population ?

Comment: yes, only the number of genes varies in two files. Total experimental values are same for all the genes in 2 files.More clearly, each gene in 2 files are measured on 400  samples.@CathG

Comment: so you've got your 2 matrices with same number of rows : matrix1 : 400 rows and 8000 columns, matrix2: 400 rows and 200 columns. The function should work with these 2 matrices. (else, like I said, function `cor` can work)

Comment: Sorry for confusion. Kindly check my edit in the main post. I included how the file looks like @CathG

Comment: well, you can transpose the matrices with `t` (if the gene names are in the 1st column, you can pass them as rownames and then delete the first column) to have 2 matrices with 400 rows each...